# How to use variable correctly inside this function?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have used -

```
<article <?php post_class( 'post-excerpt' ); ?>>
```

with WordPress successfully in the past, but would like to use this inside a function, but cannot get the correct output. It will output the class names, but not inside the tag where they should be.

This is what I have inside my function currently -

```
$post_class = post_class( 'post-excerpt' );

$html .= "<article $post_class>";
```

Which leaves me with -

```
class="post-563 post type-post status-publish format-standard has-post-thumbnail hentry category-general-news tag-audio tag-blog tag-branding tag-featured post-
```

output to the page in the wrong place, and an empty article tag??

many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`post_class` echos the class out. From the [post_class docs](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/post_class):

> If you would prefer to have the post classes returned instead of
>   echoed, you would want to use get_post_class().

I.e:

```
$post_class = get_post_class( 'post-excerpt' );

$html .= "<article class='".implode(' ',$post_class)."'>";
```

Comment: Thanks I get an error message with that though -

Notice: Array to string conversion

Comment: @FlavaFlav2013 Ah, checking the docs that returns an array. Will update.